# Does one's threatened area extend behind and to one side?

Tags: opportunity-attack, star-wars-saga-edition

We have recently started playing Star Wars Saga Edition after Episode VII rekindled the fire. Each of us are taking turns in Game Mastering, but it's been nearly 15+ years since I last had any experience in role playing.

It's my understanding that your threatened area is considered to be those NPCs adjacent to your character. On your side, front, or back side is what I would consider a threatened area. Would a character that has a target behind them and on their side get an attack of opportunity?

Comment: These should probably really be two questions; they're both about threatened areas, but are otherwise distinct.

Comment: 1) Star Wars Saga Edition and Star Wars d20 are two different games, so I've removed the [[tag:star-wars-d20]] tag. 2) Your question about Withdrawal is a separate question from your question about what area a character threatens, and we have a one-question-per-question-post site format; I've removed your second question, but you're welcome to re-ask it in its own post. (You can see the removed text, if you need to copy and paste it, by using the edit history feature: click **edited [time] ago** under your post to see the edit history.)

Comment: Apart from that, welcome to RPG.se! Take the [tour] to see what we're about, and if you have any questions about how things work you can check the [Help], or ask a support question on our “behind the scenes” site, [meta].

Answer (score 1):

Saga-Edition SW works more or less like other WotC games that include attacks of opportunities.

The game does not recognize facing; there is no explicit "front" or "behind". There is only distance between characters.

By default, characters threaten the 8 squares directly adjacent to them. Reach weapons/attacks allow a character to threaten more squares.

Also, in order to threaten a square, you must be armed with an appropriate weapon. It must be one of: a natural weapon, a melee weapon, a pistol, a carbine, or any weapon with a folded stock. So if you're wielding a Heavy Blaster Rifle, you don't get to threaten your area (since it doesn't have a folding stock).

That being said, mounting a bayonet on your HBR *does* allow you to threaten squares (but only with the bayonet's damage).